# How to install dlib in django azure web app service

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, dlib

I want to publish a django web app in azure that uses dlib and opencv for processing images

When trying to deploy the app through local code, it fails with dlib unable to install due to cmake not found. I tried using windows machine also but received same error.

CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

How do I install dlib in an azure webapp?

Comment: Do you use Azure WebApp on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows environment, you can directly install `dlib` for Python from a packaged wheel file.

You can download it from https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/ and then install it via command `pip install dlib-<version>-win_amd64.whl`, as the figure below.

[image]

Please refer to the blog [`How to install the Dlib library for Python 3 on Windows`](https://pysource.com/2019/03/20/how-to-install-dlib-for-python-3-on-windows/) or [the PyPI webpage of `dlib` package](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/) to know more details.

Hope it helps.